# не получается задать 2 атрибута с датой

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

Пытаюсь создать таблицу художников, где будет дата рождения и смерти, 
но когда задаю значение date как NUll? выдаёт ошибку
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как можно решить эту проблему?

Comment: в настройках базы (.ini или my.cnf - не помню) есть свойство sql-mode (искать в районе [mysqld]). так вот, оно по умолчанию стоит в NO_ZERO_DATE и NO_ZERO_IN_DATE.... ..можно его убить

Comment: Не могу найти, php.ini нет

Comment: зачем php.ini если это настройки базы?